# Homebrew Errors from running 'brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8'

Tags: java, react-native, homebrew

I am getting the following errors after trying to install the Java Development Kit via brew:

```
> Updating Homebrew...
> ==> Tapping homebrew/cask Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask'... remote:
> Enumerating objects: 2, done. remote: Counting objects: 100% (2/2),
> done. remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done. error: RPC
> failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60 fatal:
> the remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack
> failed Error: Failure while executing; `git clone
> https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask` exited with
> 128. Follow the instructions here:   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:285:in `safe_system'
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/tap.rb:273:in `install'
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:147:in `run'
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:97:in `run'
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/cask.rb:9:in `cask'
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:112:in `<main>'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like `curl` issue, you can `brew install curl` to fix it.

BTW, `brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8` for my Mojave machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dwnld Java SE Development Kit 8u261 macOS version and install https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html
2. See installed jdk’s. ->   /usr/libexec/java_home -V
3. Set path ->  export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
4. Check version ->  java --version
5. Check path set for java ->  which java